# Анимация изображений в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно сделать анимацию бегущего человека в WPF, с передвижением Image все ок, можно ли, как-нибудь в процессе выполнения анимации передвижения изменять не только расположение Image, но и его Source? Насколько знаю в WPF нельзя анимировать Source.

```cs
   private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap1 = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap1.BeginInit();
            bitmap1.UriSource = new Uri("Resources/runsprite1.png", UriKind.Relative);
            bitmap1.EndInit();
            Image1run.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;

            Image1run.Source = bitmap1;
            DoubleAnimation run_animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            run_animation.From = 0;
            run_animation.To = 300;           
            Image1run.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, run_animation);

        }
```

Comment: Может это поможет?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282137/wpf-animate-image-source-change

Comment: @IgorIlyichyov Спасибо большое)